# Studying electronic filters; how do I've to find the following complex argument limits?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

$$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow0} \left(\arg\left(\frac{a+b+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)}{a+b+f+g+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(i\omega L\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega C}\right)}\right)\right)$$

$$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow \infty} \left(\arg\left(\frac{a+b+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)}{a+b+f+g+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(i\omega L\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega C}\right)}\right)\right)$$

$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{c+C}{cCl+cCL}}\Longrightarrow\arg\left(\frac{a+b+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)}{a+b+f+g+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(i\omega L\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega C}\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is to multiply the denominator and numerator by $j\omega$. This will eliminate the $\frac{1}{j\omega}$ form, which would make your limit undefined. For the first equation, you would get:
$$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow0} \left(\arg\left(\frac{a+b+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)}{a+b+f+g+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(i\omega L\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega C}\right)}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{\omega\rightarrow0} \left(\arg\left(\frac{a+b+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)}{a+b+f+g+\left(i\omega l\right)+\left(i\omega L\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{i\omega C}\right)}*\frac{i\omega}{i\omega}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{\omega\rightarrow0} \left(\arg\left(\frac{a(i\omega)+b(i\omega)+\left(-\omega^2 l\right)+\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}{(i\omega)(a+b+f+g)+\left(-\omega^2 l\right)+\left(-\omega^2 L\right)+\left(\frac{1}{ c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{ C}\right)}\right)\right)$$
You now have a limit which you can directly evaluate.
$$=\lim_{\omega\rightarrow0} \left(\arg\left(\frac{0+0+0+\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}{0+0+0+\left(\frac{1}{ c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{ C}\right)}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{\omega\rightarrow0} \left(\arg\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{ c}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{ C}\right)}\right)\right)$$
Since this function is purely real, the argument must be zero.
$$\arg(x+iy)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Comment: show me how!???

Comment: That should make more sense. You did duplicate your first limit, just FYI.